# Cannot retrieve value passed from controller. Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, information-retrieval

I'm having trouble passing value from controller to my next controller.

I have used the following code:

In BillController:

```
return redirect('pdf')->with($sid);
```

In route:

```
Route::get('pdf', 'PdfController@invoice');
```

In my PdfController:

```
class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function invoice() 
    {
        $student = Student::where('id',$sid)->first();

        foreach ($student->fees as $fee) {
            $fees= $fee;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem here? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there are a number of ways to pass values:

**1. Session Flash message** (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

First you need to set a key and value with your redirect:

```
// Method phpdoc - public function with($key, $value = null)
return redirect('pdf')->with('sid', $sid);
```

You can access input values via the \Illuminate\Http\Session object:

```
// Have a look at the Session values - dd(Session::all());
$sid = Session::get('sid');
```

**2. Form submits** (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests)

If you post values, you can access them through the Request object

```
public function invoice(Request $request)
    {
        $sid = $request->get('sid');
```

**3 . Via URL**

routes.php

```
Route::get('sid/{sid}, 'PdfController@invoice')->name('invoice);
```

Redirect call (adds $sid into the route):

```
return redirect()->route('invoice', [$sid]);
```

Controller:
To get the value just ask in the controller.

```
public function index($sid)
```

Comment: It is returning nothing. When i tried to return the value with:
$id = $request->get('sid');
   return $id;
It showing a blank page without returning any value.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think it should work now. I've also added some info about passing info via a URL, which might work for you too.